Trying to connect to Oracle SQL on AWS using Python
I'm trying to connect to Oracle SQL on AWS using Python. I have cx_Oracle installed, ORacle Instant Client path set, and can't seem to figure out the host and service_name. I've checked some past posts, googled, and can't seem to find it. Sorry if this is obvious, thank you for your time
Python Script:
import cx_Oracle

username = 'Think I have this one done'
password = 'assuming this is just the password'
host = 'is this the endpoint?'
port = 'This one is figured out'
service_name = 'is this the endpoint?'

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name=service_name)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dsn)

cursor = connection.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM your_table"

cursor.execute(query)

for row in cursor:
    print(row)

cursor.close()
connection.close()

I've tried Google, checking tutorials, looking through stack overflow and other resources.

Your question appears to be "What are the connection details for connecting to Oracle on AWS?"

What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

That's a really good way to phrase it MTO! Thanks

I used python oracle db library provided by oracle, it doesn't require any additional setup. It contains complied driver part of module.
Note: do check inbound rules of oracle database and verify oracle server is reachable using command telnet <host> <port>
Ref:

https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/autonomous-database-serverless/doc/connecting-python-prepare.html


Thanks, I'm looking forward to checking this out!
